# Memory leak involving an unloaded shared object?

Tags: c++11, data-structures, segmentation-fault, abstract-data-type

I am trying to understand this programming problem whereby I am supposed to guess the data structures. I am having a slight issue with my program.

PROBLEM: I have no clue as to why my program always gets killed with signal 11 (segmentation fault) but it works and compiles fine.

About the program: n would be number of integer sets ; it takes in an integer p (command) and integer data and pushes/pops into the following data structures. I've use a bool as flag to check the statuses. Am I right to believe the structures would be destroyed after the while loop as it goes out of scope?

```
int main(){

    int n;

    while (cin >> n && n != 0){
        stack<int> mystack;
        queue<int> myqueue;
        priority_queue<int> maxq;

        bool isstack = true;
        bool isqueue = true;
        bool ispq = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            int p, data;
            cin >> p >> data; 

            if (p == 1){
                if (isqueue) myqueue.push(data);
                if (isstack) mystack.push(data);
                if (ispq) maxq.push(data);
            } else if (p == 2){
                    if ((mystack.empty() || mystack.top() != data) && isstack) isstack = false;
                    else mystack.pop();
                    if ((myqueue.empty() || myqueue.front() != data) && isqueue) isqueue = false; 
                    else myqueue.pop();
                    if ((maxq.empty() || maxq.top() != data) && ispq) ispq = false; 
                    else maxq.pop();
                }       
        }       

        if (isstack && !(isqueue || ispq)) cout << "stack" << endl;
        else if (isqueue && !(isstack || ispq)) cout << "queue" << endl;
        else if (isstack && (ispq || isqueue) || (isqueue && ispq)) cout << "not sure" << endl;
        else if (ispq && !(isstack || isqueue)) cout << "priority queue" << endl;
        else cout << "impossible" << endl;
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run it in the debugger. It should stop at the point of a segfault.

Comment: You need to set LD_LIBRARY_PATH to let Valgrind know where your libraries are, so that valgrind can give the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the data structures you’ve used are local scope to while, so they get destructed at the end of while loop.

Unless you provide for what input you’re seeing segmentation fault, it’s hard to say. Or run it in debug mode, your program should break at line where seg fault occurs.

Answer (score -1):

I tried to run this code.

This code threw an exception when you pop after 'isstack' was changed to false.

The exception was 'Expression: deque empty before pop'.

After the variable changed false, always condition statements are return false.

So you tried to pop at empty stack.

That is a just logical bug.

Comment: This does not qualify as an answer.

Comment: I did not pop after i changed 'isstack' to false. Its a condition if-else, think you missed a line